# Cross-Origin Request Blocked while sending data via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

hey guys i am trying to send data via ajax to my api website so I can insert it in my database
but it gives me error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource

Here is my ajax code

```
    var email = $('#my-email').val();
    var domain = $('#my-domain').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://example.com/api/check.php",
        data: { email: email, domain: domain },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
        
        },
        error: function() {
          console.log("Error sending AJAX request");
        }
    });
```

and this is my php code

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        //request is ajax
        include_once("UserConfig.php");
        
        $user = new UserFreePlugin();
    
        $user_email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);  // Get email
        $user_domain = filter_var($_POST['domain'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);  // Get domain

        if (!empty($user_email) && !empty($user_domain)) // Get license
        {
            $created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $user->insertUser($user_email,$user_domain,$created_at);
        }
        else
        {
            die();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        header("location: ../");
    }
```

i'm using code xmlhttprequest so i can request only by ajax

Comment: [from comments under deleted answer] _"but it works only when i remove $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']"_ - so that header is likely either _not_ set, or not with the exact value you are checking for; therefor your script redirects to `../`, and the response to _that_ request then does presumably not contain an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header ... hence the error.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for helping, i removed the redirect from my script, but still give me the same error, in your opinion what is the problem?

Comment: Maybe your browser still has the redirect cached, try in a private window or clear cache. If that's not it, then you will have to investigate a little deeper, what's actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your ajax request

```js
crossDomain: true
```